# Quotients of Koszul algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, koszul-algebras

Let $A$ be a noncommutative Koszul algebra (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_algebra) for a definition of Koszul) and let $c \in A$ be a central element. Will the quotient of $A$ by the ideal generated by $c$ again be Koszul. If not what is a counter example and what else could I require to ensure Koszulity?

Comment: Did you look at the book *Quadratic algebras*? The answer in general is no because Koszul algebras are quadratic, but I recall the book contains some results in the positive direction.

Comment: Is it easy to see that Koszul algebras are quadratic?

Comment: Yes. This is probably in the book I mentioned. You compute Tor2. Tor1 informs on the generators and Tor2 on the relations. The diagonal condition gives the algebra is generated in degree 1 (Tor1) with relations in degree 2 (Tor2).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: Require $c$ to be a homogeneous element of degree $1$ and a nonzero-divisor.  This is certainly enough.

Comment: @Leonid: Let $c$ be a homogeneous element of degree $2$, and we were to quotient by $c-1$? I am thinking here of the algebra of representatble functions of of the algebraic group $SU(2)$.

Comment: @DidierdeMontblazon What's your definition of a Koszul algebra, and aren't they supposed to be graded, by definition?  What is the grading on $A/(c-1)$, if c is a homogeneous element of degree $2$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no assumptions, obviously the answer is no.  You didn't even require that c is homogeneous.

If $c$ has any components of degree $>2$, then I think the answer is that the quotient is never Koszul: Koszul algebras are quadratic.

If $c$ has degree 0,1 or 2, then certainly there are cases where $A/(c)$ will be Koszul:

- $A=K\langle x,y\rangle$ the free algebra on 2 variables over any field $K$ is Koszul, and $c= xy-yx$ gives $A/c=K[x,y]$ which is again Koszul.
- If $A$ is free or polynomial, the quotient by any degree 1 element will be free or polynomial on one fewer generators.
- If you have a Koszul quotient of the path algebra of a quiver, you can sometimes kill a vertex and get something Koszul.  For example, if $x,y$ are the edges of an oriented 2-cycle, the quotient $xy=0$ is 5-dimensional and Koszul, and killing either vertex gives the base field.

I suspect that this is not "typical" behavior (for example, this paper shows that there are quadratic quotients of polynomial rings which are not Koszul: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09145.pdf), but don't have the time/energy to come up with a bunch of counter-examples right now.

Answer (score 5):

No, take for instance $A = k[x]$ and $c = x^3$.  In my opinion, the point is that Koszulity and commutativity/centrality are not related to one other.  So I doubt there is any good statement along the lines of what you are looking for.